# Do not append if it already exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have one file called `ClientList.txt` that has a output of:

```
client1.hello.com
client2.hello.com
client3.hello.com
```

And I use this script to append the values of the `ClientList.txt` in a `output.txt` file. Code:

```
with open("ClientList.txt", "r") as infile:
  with open("output.txt", "a") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write("".join(["clients name: ",line.strip(), ", clients URL: ", line.strip(), ", service: VIP\n"]))
```

Output:

```
clients name: client1.hello.com, clients URL: client1.hello.com, service: VIP
clients name: client2.hello.com, clients URL: client2.hello.com, service: VIP
clients name: client3.hello.com, clients URL: client3.hello.com, service: VIP
```

Question: In the future I would like to update the `ClientList.txt` with new clients (example: `client4.hello.com` etc.). Is it possible to not append the value if it already exists in the `output.txt` file?

Comment: I think you should use a database instead of a text file at that point.

Comment: yes, but you don't want to do that.

Comment: Of course, yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files are just simple streams of text, so they don't support any notion of "append this row if no equivalent row exists"; you have to build that manually.

You *can* do that with just a plain text file, but it's clunky and potentially inefficient. What you have to do is read through the file and check for yourself. You can optimize that by reading through the file once and storing it in a set instead of doing it over and over again, but it's still a bit ugly:

```
with open("ClientList.txt", "r") as infile:
    with open("output.txt", "r") as outfile:
        existing = set(outfile)
    with open("output.txt", "a") as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            outline = "".join(["clients name: ",line.strip(), ", clients URL: ", line.strip(), ", service: VIP\n"])
            if outline not in existing:
                outfile.write(outline)
                existing.add(outline)
```

If you're wondering how that `set(outfile)` works: A file object in Python is an iterable of lines. That's why `for line in infile:` works. And it means we can construct a set of all of the lines just by passing that iterable to `set`.

---

You might be better off with a database.

The simplest database is probably the `dbm` format that comes builtin to Python, which works a lot like a Python dict. Just as you can't store the same key in a dict multiple times (repeats just overwrite the originals), the same is true with a `dbm`. So:

```
with open("ClientList.txt", "r") as infile:
    with dbm.open("output.dbm", "c") as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            outline = "".join(["clients name: ",line.strip(), ", clients URL: ", line.strip(), ", service: VIP\n"])
            outfile[outline] = ""
```

Or, better, actually *use* the key-value-ness. If it's the `clients name` rather than the whole string that has to be unique, make that the key, and the rest the value:

```
with open("ClientList.txt", "r") as infile:
    with dbm.open("output.dbm", "c") as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            outline = json.dumps({
                "clients name": line.strip(),
                "clients URL": line.strip(),
                "service": "VIP"})
            outfile[clients_name] = outline
```

Then, of course, your output is a `dbm` database rather than a textfile, which only works if the thing that's consuming your data knows how to use a `dbm`. But if you're writing the thing that's consuming your data, that shouldn't be a problem.

---

Of course you have multiple values to associate with each key, so the ideal solution is probably either a multi-column key-value database, a document database, or a relational database. Python comes with a simple relational database called `sqlite3`, which you could use something like this (untested):

```
with open("ClientList.txt", "r") as infile:
    db = sqlite3.connect('output.sqlite')
    db.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Clients COLUMNS (
        Name TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
        URL TEXT,
        Service TEXT)''')
    for line in infile:
        db.execute('''INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Clients (Name, URL, Service)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?)''', (line.strip(), line.strip(), 'VIP'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the file size is not too big, I'd go with the simplestest solution and just read the data into memory, alter it, write it back. That's extremely simple in python and still fast.

```
with open('ClientList.txt') as f:
    data = set(f.readlines())
data.add('nextValue\n')
with open('ClientList.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(data)
```

Comment: But this doesn't preserve the order of the existing lines, and it's not that much simpler than just checking each line before appending it.

Comment: I don't see order as a requirement.

Comment: Well, there is no requirement spec given, but his existing code is appending lines in order, and randomly changing things without even mentioning that you're doing so is usually not a great idea when you don't know what the spec is.

Comment: Some of your proposals don't preserve order, too. Anyways, I don't really see a point in debating this. The OP already picked your answer, which is very elaborate. Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a validation like this:`
def exist(file_name, link):
    with open(file_name) as tmp:
        for line in tmp:
            if link in line:
                return True
    return False

with open("ClientList.txt", "r") as infile:
with open("output.txt", "a") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if not exist('output.txt',line):
            outfile.write("".join(["clients name: ",line.strip(), ", clients URL: ", line.strip(), ", service: VIP\n"]))
`
even closing and opening the file every time may not be a good idea, you could modify the function so that you maintain the reference to the file and you only have to move the pointer at the beginning and start the search one more time, you could also have all the content in memory and perform a search there directly, but that work will be your decision

Answer (score -1):

Surely you can just check if the client's name is in output.txt like:

```
with open("ClientList.txt", "r") as infile:
  with open("output.txt", "a") as outfile:
    file=outfile.read()
    for line in infile:
        clientName=line.strip()
        if (clientName in file)==False:
            outfile.write("".join(["clients name: ",line.strip(), ", clients URL: ", line.strip(), ", service: VIP\n"]))
```

Not sure if that would work but it should do.

Comment: The edited version will sort of work with some changes, but (a) you're doing a substring match of just part of the line against the entire file contents, which can get false matches, and which is also slow, (b) you'd have to reopen and reread the entire file for every line (otherwise you can write the same row twice in a row and it won't see the first version), and (c) you can't read a file opened in "a" mode.

Comment: Does it give an error or just not give the right result?

Comment: Well I did think about that. For a) I just thought it would highly unlikely the client name would appear in any other place. For b) you can just read it once then copy over every loop. For c) I believe you can open it in r+ mode which allows both reading and appending

Comment: b) if you just copy it every time, it won’t have new lines in it. c) Sure, you can use r+, but then you have to seek to the start before each read and seek to the end before each append, which makes it even more complicated and inefficient.

Comment: Yeah I suppose. Just trying to help